# Hive: Removing Duplicate Rows from Table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which contains millions of records and all the records have duplicates. So I am trying to extract all the distinct rows in the table.
Here's the query I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE unique_table AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM duplicates_table;
```

Is this the efficient way to do this job? Or is there a way to remove duplicate rows without creating a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table_name SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name;
```